# Show that $a^3+b^5=7^{7^{7^7}}$ has no solutions with $a,b\in \mathbb Z.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Show that $a^3+b^5=7^{7^{7^7}}$ has no solutions with $a,b\in \mathbb Z.$

I can't really get anywhere on this. I can't see how to find $7^{7^{7^{7}}}$ in any modulus other than $7$ or $6$, both of which are no use.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: You can find it modulo any prime with Fermat's Little Theorem

Comment: And modulo any number not divisible by $7$ using Euler's theorem.

Comment: You are right to think of reducing modulo a prime. However, rather than looking for a modulus that will reduce $7^{7^{7^7}}$, we should look for one that reduces $a^3$ and $b^5$. As amcalde comments, we should be able to calculate $7^{7^{7^7}}$ mod any prime; however, it will only be very useful if $a^3$ and $b^5$ simplify.

Comment: Anyway I think user133281's answer settles it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm clearly being an idiot here, but how can we apply Fermat's little theorem here. Don't we require it to be in the form $a^p$ to work mod $p$? Again, sorry if this is frustrating to explain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Euler's theorem, you can compute $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 19 \mod 31$. However, $19$ is not expressible as the sum of a cube and a fifth power modulo $31$.

In other words, $a^3 + b^5 = 7^{7^{7^7}}$ has no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z}$, so it also has no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}$.

In general, with this type of question, it is useful to work modulo a prime $p$ such that the exponents involved divide $p-1$. The reason for this is that when $n \mid p-1$, $a^n$ cannot take many different values modulo $p$ (this is a consequence of Euler's theorem). Here $3$ and $5$ both divide $p-1=30$.

**Edit:** Euler's theorem can help you to compute $7^{7^{7^7}} \pmod {31}$ as follows. Since $(7,31)=1$ and $\phi(31)=30$, we have $7^{30} \equiv 1 \mod 31$. Therefore, $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 7^k \mod 31$, where $k$ is the remainder of $7^{7^7}$ upon division by $30$. In order to compute this, it suffices to compute $7^{7^7}$ modulo $2$, $3$ and $5$. For $7^{7^7} \pmod 5$ you can again use Euler's theorem to reduce this to $7^{\ell} \mod 5$, where $\ell$ is the remainder of $7^7$ upon division by $\phi(5)=4$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being an idiot here, but I have Euler's theorem as $a^{\phi (n)}\equiv1 ($mod $n)$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. I can't see how we can get $7^{7^{7^7}}$ in that form. Again, sorry if I'm missing something blatantly obvious. Thanks

Comment: @user307463 You want $7^{7^{7^7}}$ mod $31$. So you need to calculate $7^{7^7}$ mod $\phi(31) = 30$. And then $7$ is still relatively prime to $30$, so you want to calculate $7^7$ mod $\phi(30) = 8$. Which is $7^7 \equiv (-1)^7 \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: Then $7^7$ mod $30$ is $13$, and $7^{13}$ mod $31$ is $19$, which is your answer. Anyway this kind of modular exponentiation is confusing if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: Interesting (+1) How a person can think of modulo $31$? :)

Comment: @iamvegan This answer actually comments on that -- look for a prime $p$ where $\phi(p)$ is divisible by both $3$ and $5$ :)

Comment: As mentioned above, look for a prime $p$ such that $p-1$ is a multiple of the exponents involved. For $x^3+y^4$, look mod $13$. For $x^2+y^5$, look mod $11$. The reason for this is that when $n \mid p-1$, $a^n$ cannot take many different values modulo $p$ by Euler's theorem.

Comment: @user133281, how can we quickly show that 19 is not expressible as the sum of a cube and a fifth power modulo 31 please?