# Prove that $19^{19} = m^4+n^3$ has no solution with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $19^{19}$ can never be of the form $m^4+n^3$. $m$ and $n$ are integers.

This is what I tried: 19=18+1 and applied binomial theorem and that have $m^4 + n^3 + 1= 18k$. I also tried checking last digits of $m^4$ and $n^3$ and their sum's. $19^{19}$ will end in $9$. Please help me now.

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: I'm afraid simply asking a question and expecting an answer won't gain you respect on here. Please explain what you have tried :-) If this is a question on a class worksheet, then check your lecture notes from previous classes. The information in these notes will most likely enable you to solve this problem yourself ! PS I did not downvote.

Comment: $3\cdot4=12=\varphi(13)$. If this question were not closed, I'd suggest trying some small prime modulo, but - - -

Comment: I am sorry, I am new. Now please help

Comment: @Rupert: Do *not* let yourself get discouraged.

Comment: But how shall I prove it now.... So I have to post this question again?

Comment: How do we remove the " hold" from this q?

Comment: @barak, please share the solution, I will be very grateful

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906709/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Because $3 \mid \phi(13)$ and $4 \mid \phi(13)$, $m^4$ and $n^3$ cannot take all possible values modulo $13$. If you can show that $19^{19} = m^4 + n^3$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$, then it also does not have solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Bigger hint:** One can check that $m^4+n^3$ is never congruent to $7$ modulo $13$ by trying all possible values for $m$ and $n$ modulo $13$. If you show that $19^{19} \equiv 7 \mod 13$, then you can deduce that $19^{19} = m^4+n^3$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ∅(13) what does this notation mean? I didn't understand the solution

Comment: Ignore what you didn't understand. Just calculate all possible residues modulo 13.

Comment: @ Ivan 1,3,4,9,10,12 are the residues. Now what shall I do.

Comment: @Rupert $19^{19}\equiv7\bmod13$, which is not in the list of residues, so the equation is inconsistent.

Comment: Which is the first theorem which is used?

Comment: If 3 and 4 divide the totient function of 13 then what does this give us? And by which theorem? Could someone please provide a bit more elaborate proof?

Comment: I can show that 19^19 = 7mod13. But how to do check for all m and n modulo 13. What does this mean. Please give one or two examples.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Determine which residues $m^4$ can take modulo $13$. Also determine which residues $n^3$ can take modulo $13$. Then check that none of these residues can be combined to get $7$.